# Importance sampling in context of graphics

Tags: graphics

I am currently writing a program which uses importance sampling. All is going well so far, however I have two minor queries that I would like to know about.

1. What is the most basic job that we would expect importance sampling to do?
2. For an arbitrarily large number of samples, what is the difference between a result with importance sampling and one without it?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your “minor quiries” seem more like fundamental information. We expect you to try to find answers to your questions yourself before posting on stack overflow. What resources have you already consulted to answer your questions? Which parts of those resources were confusing to you?

Comment: I don't understand your first query.